# aws websocket api event requestContext not defined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

A few months ago I built the lambda function with this code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    
    const route = event.requestContext.routeKey;
    const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
    
    switch(route) {
        case '$connect':
            break;
        case '$disconnect':
            break;
        case '$default':
            break;
        case 'createRoom':
            break;
        case 'allowAccess':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'declineAccess':
            break;
    }
};
```

But now, when I console.log(event) I see it isn't requestContext anymore on event object, just an action property.

Comment: i assume you use the api gateway to communicate you lambda, if yes then did you have the "Lmabda Proxy Integration" option checked?

Comment: @Ruben yes I did